# Deploy React no Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, react

Galera bom dia, fiz um deploy de um app react no heroku, mas ele está totalmente sem css.
Preciso de um help pq não faço nem ideia doq possa ser.

Answer (score 0):

Tente esses passos:

```
heroku create -b https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
git add .
git commit -m "react-create-app on Heroku"
git push heroku master
heroku open
```